# How to track user behaviour in C# visual studio for Word Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ms-word, word-addins

I want to find out which button (e.g. button ID, name) the user has clicked on in Word 2010 with the help of C# and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I can imagine that there is a possibility to print in console what the user did while running the word add-in solution.

I'm trying to address a specific button in the controls tab via VBA, but could not find the exact name and ID of that specific button yet. I hope there's a way to find out.

Edit:

```
 Sub ControlProperties()
    Dim Answer
    Answer = MsgBox("You are about to edit property parameters. Continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Properties")
    If Answer = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Here implement code to continue..."
    Else
    End If
    End Sub
```

Cutom UI editor entry:

```
<command idMso="ControlProperties" enabled="true" onAction="ControlProperties" />
```

My goal is just to pop up that msgbox where the user gets warned that he is about to edit parameters and continue the original function of the button. But with code above ControlProperties is gettin disabled completely.

Best Regards.

Comment: so you want .Net to find something that is happening in VBA? Also, what have you tried, where is your code

Comment: Not quite. I want to intercept the "Properties" button in Controls tab in Developer (in Word 2010). Well, actually vba should prompt a message when you click on it and with yes you can continue this function, with no you can cancel. The problem is i can't find a way to address that button. So far I know the button has idMso="ControlProperties"

Comment: edit your question and show the code here

Comment: But this does not work, as vba does nothing. So i thought there must be another way to figure out how to address this button and to intervent the click on it. So i thought maybe c# has a tracking function to find out where the user clicked and on what he clicked, in order to locate that button

Answer (score 0):

Found a way that worked with " CancelDefault = False ":

```
Sub ControlProperties()
    Dim Answer
    Answer = MsgBox("You are about to edit property parameters. Continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Properties")
    If Answer = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Here implement code to continue..."
CancelDefault = False
    Else
    End If
    End Sub
```